# Speed, CouchDB views and alternatives

Tags: database, performance, couchdb

I have large data set, which I want to query. The query does not change but the underlying data does. From what I read, I could construct a "view" and query it. Also, I read that Couch DB knows how to update the view when data is changed so I assume querying the view again would be still fast.

My questions are, do I understand CounchDB's views correctly? I don't need any other feature of CouchDB, I don't even need SQL, all I want is fast same query over changing data. Could I use something else? If I would use, say, good old MySQL would it really be slower than CouchDB (read: in the above scenario, how would various DBs approximately perform?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone can answer your question given the information you have provided.

Indexes in a relational database are analogous to CouchDB views.  In both cases, they store a pre-sorted instance of the data and the database keeps that instance in sync with the canonical data.  Both types of database transparently use the index/view to speed up subsequent queries of the form that the index/view was designed for.

Without indexes/views, queries must scan the whole collection of `n` records of data and they execute in `O(n)` time.  When a query benefits from an indexes/views, it executes in `O(log n)` time.

But that's speaking very broadly of the performance curve with respect to the volume of data.  A given database could have such speedy performance in certain cases that it out-performs another product no matter what.  It's hard to make generalizations that brand X is always faster than brand Y.  The only way to be sure about a specific case is to try that case in both databases and measure the performance.

Comment: I knew that indexes are pre-sorted (i.e. O(log N)) but I thought views get automatically populated with newly updated data, so there would be no search at all. In other words, I thought views are very different than indexes, what performance goes... Btw, you say I provided not enough information, could you please be more specific? Like the amount of data? I also thought it is more important that the query stays the same and data changes than anything else....

Comment: Which product has best performance depends a lot on your specific queries, and what indexes/views you have defined.  That's what I mean by not enough information.  Each product has its strengths and weaknesses, so you can optimize only after knowing what queries you need to optimize for.

Comment: Also: you can use indexes to avoid a search if the index includes all the columns you need in your result.  This is called a *covering index*.  Of course in many RDBMS brands, you can define an index only for columns in one table at a time, so it may be less versatile than a CouchDB view.

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment is completely correct. Enjoy!

The only performance trick worth mentioning is that you may see a boost if you `emit()` all of the data you need from the view and never use the `?include_docs` feature, because include_docs causes CouchDB to go back into the main database and retrieve the original doc that caused that view row. In other words, you can `emit()` everything you need into your view index (more space but faster), or you can use the reference back to the original document (less space but slower.)